# aptana custom auto-formatting?

Tags: php, aptana, formatting

Using Aptana Studio 3 for php, curious if I can customize how the auto-format formats (pressing CRTL-SHIFT-F formats the current file for you)

I'd like to change something rather small, make it so brackets end up below their conditionals, for's, whiles, etc.

```
if(blah)
{
    stuff...
}
```

instead of

```
if(blah) {
    stuff...
}
```

cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to:

Window => Preferences

Select the Aptana dropdown
Select Formatter

This gives you some pretty nifty control on some common a